# Wordpress on multiple development servers

Tags: wordpress

We have a Wordpress site on multiple servers. Updating Wordpress or plugins only does it for one server then we have to sync it to all other servers. Is there any way to automate this process? We do all updates manually. Any further information regarding this matter will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the command line?

Comment: yes, we usually use rsync to sync the files to another servers then publish to all other servers from there using the terminal.

Comment: You can set up a very simple script using rsync then.  Or look into something like Capistrano.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Git - Pull from 1 central repository.

Comment: so we will have to put all files in the central repo and point the domain and subdomains to it? Any further information is greatly appreciated. This is the first time I have worked with wordpress and its frustrating and hard to find solutions online for this problem.

Comment: Central repo being a private Git setup (your remotes). Then you put the WordPress install with all your plugins and themes in that repo. Then clone the repo to your dev sites. You can later work in commit hooks or use cron to do periodic pulls.